# Lost Mac DVD, how can I get a new copy of the disk?

Tags: mac, dvd

I bought a MacBook Pro, unfortunately I lost the DVD that came with it. Where can I get a new one?

Comment: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Apple sell replacement restore DVDs. The closest thing would be to purchase a [Snow Leopard install DVD](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MAC_OS_X_SNGL?mco=MTAyNTQzNzE). They're only £26 (Sterling) and can do almost everything you might use the restore DVD for.

Comment: Or 29 EUR or 29 USD, etc.

Comment: You could call the apple support. They will need your serial number and then they will send an replacement for a fee. But if you don't need the hardware tests you may be better off with an update dvd.